# How is Trello iPhone app developed?

Tags: ios, web-applications, frameworks, native-code, trello

I was wondering which libraries or frameworks Trello iphone app is using.

**Is it a webapp with JS framework? if yes, which one?**

**Or is it native? which frameworks for this here?**

I'm curious because I really like the UI, and has searched the internet without luck.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm on the Trello team and wrote the iPhone app. It's all native code except for the attachment viewer, which is just a WebView. We use RestKit to communicate with our API and help cache the data locally to CoreData. Otherwise, it's just a bunch of custom UIViews and UIViewControllers.

Comment: Wow that's just great. I'm already using RestKit - I thought you were using some special framework with benefits for the coding effects. Thanks for your quick resopnse.

Comment: How do you push live data from server to ios app?

APNS or sockets or what? :) 

I'm curious 
Thanks

Comment: All data is pulled at the moment.

Comment: Justin Gallagher: So you keep a persistent connection open, right?

Comment: You cache data locally, but why don't you allow to add new cards offline? I like web app, but I don't like iphone app because it doesn't work offline.

Comment: @JustinGallagher I really like how you guys did the Google auth on the trello app. When I use the google sign in framework it pops us out and back into the app. Did you guys do it differently to keep it all within the app?

Comment: @JustinGallagher what UI component you have used in your dashboard , its very great.

Comment: Can you suggest how you have made kanban board using native code for iOS?