# How is Trello Android app developed?

Tags: android, web-applications, trello

This is a companion question to [How is Trello iPhone app developed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700460/how-is-trello-iphone-app-developed).

Is it a webapp with JS framework? if yes, which one?

Or is it native? which frameworks for this here?

Like the questioner there, I'm curious.

Comment: Time to read the [help/dont-ask] again?

Comment: Yes, there's a reason I carefully used the same wording as the other question. Which has 5 votes and no pedantic comments about closing it. Inconsistency much?

Comment: Not much... Rules changed since then... 4 downvotes and 4 closevotes agree with me. I'm just pointing out why.

Comment: Where does the Help Center state that old questions aren't subject to the same considerations as new questions? And what rule changed exactly? IMO it's rather misleading to keep questions alive and then zerg rush other people who ask effectively the same question about another relevant topic.

Comment: There are **millions** of questions in this site... it's kind of hard to moderate them all...

Comment: It is. And yet of the 4 people who downvoted this, no-one thought to update the question it's explicitly based on.

Comment: please open a Meta question if you need further clarifications

Comment: I am pretty sure it's native app. You can ask on their board https://trello.com/b/vBqLThGO/trello-for-android-beta or https://trello.com/b/ud59t1fL/trello-for-android-development